# PM2 + Meteor not working

Tags: meteor, pm2

I get an error when trying to run it:

```
~/projects/test-app 
/usr/local/bin/meteor:3
# This is the script that we install somewhere in your $PATH (as "meteor")
```

Here is the command I run:

```
pm2 start meteor-pm2.json
```

And here is meteor-pm2.json:

```
{
  "name" : "test-app",
  "script" : "/usr/local/bin/meteor",
  "MAIL_URL":"smtp://yourmail_configuration_here",
  "MONGO_URL":"mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor",
  "ROOT_URL":"https://www.mysite.com/",
  "PORT":"3000",
  "out_file":"/home/josh/logs/app.log",
  "error_file":"/home/josh/logs/err.log"
}
```

I also try this:
cat start

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor"
PORT=3000
ROOT_URL="https://www.mysite.com/"

/usr/local/bin/meteor
```

and I run it with:

```
pm2 start ./start -x interpreter bash
```

and I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/meteor
^
ReferenceError: usr is not defined
```

when i modify the bash script by adding the export:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor"
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL="https://www.mysite.com/"

/usr/local/bin/meteor
```

I get:

```
export - SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Is pm2 trying to run the bash script in it's own special script interpreter that doesn't allow the use of export?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this `process.json` syntax is more correct:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "myAppName",
      "script": "./bundle/main.js",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
      "env": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://127.0.0.1/meteor",
        "ROOT_URL": "https://myapp.example.com/",
        "BIND_IP": "127.0.0.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

then I just start it using `run.sh` which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# This shell script starts the actual
# app in the production environtment.
#

pm2 start process.json -i max # Enable load-balancer and cluster features
```

Note: the BIND_IP env var is there to change it from the default (0.0.0.0). The 0.0.0.0 would make the app accessible around the ssl proxy layer (if you use SSL/TLS with nginx or some other web server and the BIND_IP is set to 0.0.0.0 then pretty much anyone could access it via http://myapp.example.com:3000 around the encrypted layer, unless you block that port in your web server's configuration).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got my meteor app (Telescope) working

```
 ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Telescope pm2 start main.js
```

inside .meteor/local/build

Answer (score 0):

Meteor isn't actually running from /usr/local/bin/meteor, that script is only used for bootstrapping etc, that when done redirects to ~/.meteor/meteor

*From /usr/local/bin/meteor:*

```
# All this script does is exec ~/.meteor/meteor. But what if you don't have it
# yet? In that case, it downloads a "bootstrap tarball", which contains the
# latest version of the Meteor tools, and plops it down at ~/.meteor. In fact,
# once you've run this once, you don't even really need this script: you can put
# ~/.meteor/ into your PATH, or a symlink to ~/.meteor/meteor into some other
# PATH directory. No special permissions needed!
```

So what you need to do is change your script pointer to use meteor in your "Warehouse dir" (~/meteor/meteor)

Comment: Changing the json file to "script": "/home/josh/.meteor/meteor" fails with this error:

/home/josh/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/bin/meteor:3
BUNDLE_VERSION=0.3.33
                  ^^^
.                                                                                                                                                                I found this workaround, but it's not using json file or bash script:
**pm2 start ~/.meteor/meteor -x --interpreter bash**

Answer (score 0):

This means that pm2 expects some syntax and finds another in the start script. In order to direct it to the right syntax, add this to your `config.json` file:

```
"interpreter"  : "bash"
```

P.S.: addition of this parameter to the command line didn't work